# Are BigQuery loads transactional?

Tags: google-bigquery

We had a spurious 500 error while running a load job on several CSVs:

`google.api_core.exceptions.InternalServerError: 500 BATCH contentid://None: Backend Error`

When a load fails, is the entire load backed out (like a transaction)? Or was there a partial load of only some of the CSVs we passed in with the load job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery single job is transactional, either all of the CSV files are loaded or none of them gets loaded.

Comment: Could you please add a reference, thanks!